# RaycastHit.triangleIndex alternatives

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, rtd

I am working on a Real-time destruction plugin for unity but I have run into some problems as far as mesh manipulation is concerned.

### what I am trying to do:

cut a hole out of a mesh by removing the front and back sides of the 3d mesh.

Example image

[image: Example image]

### what I am doing:

I am removing part of the original mesh (at this point it is just one triangle) cloning it, and placing it into another mesh (just background info).

what mine does/looks like

[image: what mine does/looks like]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class destroy : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject ttt;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }


    void deleteTri(int index)  // what is index? index is hit.triangleIndex the triangle that the mouse hit, this number is relative to the top rightmost triangle 
    {
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(this.gameObject);
        Destroy(clone.GetComponent<distroy>());
        Destroy(clone.GetComponent<MeshCollider>());


        Destroy(this.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>()); // removes prevouse render of shape 
         Mesh mesh = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh; // gets mesh (oop)


        int[] oldTriangles = mesh.triangles;  // current total number of triangles
        int[] oldTriangles2 = mesh.triangles;  

        int[] newTriangles = new int[mesh.triangles.Length - 3];
        int[] otherTriangles = new int[mesh.triangles.Length - 3];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int j2 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        while (j < mesh.triangles.Length)  // makeing a new list of all the vector points in the mesh when it finds the mesh you have made it skips those three vector points and finishes the list this then removes that point from the mesh 
        {
            if(j != index*3)
            {
                newTriangles[i++] = oldTriangles[j++];
                newTriangles[i++] = oldTriangles[j++];
                newTriangles[i++] = oldTriangles[j++];
            }
            else
            {
                 j += 3;
            }


            // this is for making the second mesh and is an inverse of the original code 
            if (j2 == index * 3)
            {
                otherTriangles[i2++] = oldTriangles2[j2++];
                otherTriangles[i2++] = oldTriangles2[j2++];
                otherTriangles[i2++] = oldTriangles2[j2++];
            }
            else
            {
               j2 += 3;
            }

        }
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.triangles = newTriangles;  //says this is the new mesh 
        this.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>(); // renders the mesh 

        clone.transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.triangles = otherTriangles;  //says this is the new mesh 
        clone.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>(); // renders the mesh 




    }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Ray ray2 = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(ttt.transform.position);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000.0f))
            {
                deleteTri(hit.triangleIndex);
               // print(hit.triangleIndex);
               // print(ray2.hit.triangleIndex);
                //print(ray.triangleIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem with my current code is that it only works for a plane mesh and not for a 3d mesh. This is because ray casting stops when it hits something, I need the program to detect the triangleIndex of both sides and then give/return it to me. I am lost please help!

Comment: Please review the [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)'s _"Should I use tags in titles?"_ section before re-adding your Unity tag to your question title.

Comment: Why not just run the raycast in a while loop until it doesn't hit anything?

Comment: my goal would be to move away from raycasting because it is not the most predictable of code and can do some weird and wacky stuff when you're not aligned perfectly with the object you are trying to manipulate.

Comment: I think any algorithm which solves your issue is going to be equivalent to some form of ray casting. If you're having precision issues, you could try sending multiple rays with slight x/y offsets from `mousePosition`. For example, you could add rays from the corner pixels surrounding `mousePosition`